# Open URL in Microsoft Teams tab

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to open a link in the static tab from a bot conversation. I used deep linking for this and created a link like `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{TeamsAppId}/{TeamsTabId}?webUrl={myURL}`.

The problem is that it opens the URL first in the browser asking with which app to open it with. Then, I have to click "Open in Microsoft Teams" and it opens it in the MS Teams tab.

How can I get rid of this and open the URL directly in the tab?

The manifest part that creates the static tab is

```
"staticTabs": [{
    "entityId": "com.my.tab",
    "name": "MyTab",
    "contentUrl": "https://dev.my.com/#/start",
    "scopes": [ "personal" ]
}],
```

In the example above, `TeamsTabId` is `com.my.tab`.

Comment: I'm reaching out to the Teams developer group to see if I can get some help for you on this one. Does the same/similar link work fine (w/o the hop to the browser) outside of a bot conversation?

Comment: try this way. its working for me https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{TeamsAppId}/{TeamsTabId}?msLaunch=true&enableMobilePage=true&suppressPrompt=true&webUrl=https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 5):

Related to this annoying feature, is Outlook Microsoft Teams links first opening in a browser tab. Anyone coming here please add your vote to the [uservoice request](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/34501303-open-links-to-teams-in-desktop-app) to remove that:
[image: uservoice]

Answer (score 1):

Deep links in bot conversations only work from card buttons today, not the text. We will fix that at some point but we don't have a date to share.

Comment: I actually included the URLs in cards and the behavior was as described in my question.

Comment: To elaborate on the answer: using a deep link URL in an Action.OpenUrl element does not open a new browser tab for me. 
 https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.OpenUrl.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *https*, try replacing it with *msteams*. It will directly open in MS-Teams app.
When you use msteams prefix, instead of https, the prompt menu will show like :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open these links from within Teams, it does not show the intermediate browser page (which we call a launcher page). But if you open it from a web page or an email message for example, you will see the launcher page.

Deep links work across all devices but there’s no way to avoid the intermediate launcher page on Windows/Mac.

Comment: Even from within Teams it shows that launcher page.

Comment: Could you please share the manifest file so that we can try it at our end (microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com)? Are you trying to open this deep link within a tab or a bot (conversation tab)?

Comment: I added the manifest part that defines the static tab in my manifest. I try to open the link in the static tab.