# Microsoft Teams | OAuth2 | authentication.authenticate() | Not getting prompt with provided URL

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a configurable tab in MS Teams.
For accessing graph API, using OAuth2 authentication for Microsoft.
On Button click, asking user to grant permissions for the required scope.

currently using URL [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client-id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect-url}&response_mode=query&scope=User.Read](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient-id%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect-url%7D&response_mode=query&scope=User.Read) email openid profile offline_access User.ReadBasic.All Presence.Read.All&state= to get the permission from user.

I am opening the above URL using Window.open().

Now, requirement is to open authentication window inside MS teams app.

to achieve this, I tried

1. getAuthToken() method to get user permission but not able to get permission for all the scope needed to be grant. Its just getting access for basic user details scope.
2. as per comment in [Open URL in Microsoft Teams tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963712/open-url-in-microsoft-teams-tab), tried to use teams.microsoft.com/l/entity{TeamsAppId}/{TeamsTabId}?msLaunch=true&enableMobilePage=true&suppressPrompt=true&webUrl=google.com URL to open web url in teams but it did not work
3. with the help of authentication.authenticate() method I am able to get the popup for grant permission when I open teams in browser but not working in a app

Can I get a working sample code, how can I get permission from user inside MS teams configurable tab app using Microsoft consent window?

Answer (score 0):

The handling of SSO in Teams Tabs has improved a LOT over the years, which of course is good news, but it means that the code samples and guidance has also changed, leading to many out of date examples, like the question you're referencing. As an example, you should *not* be calling the endpoint yourself - the Teams library will handle this for you. I'd suggest referring to the latest documentation, which includes C# and Node.js examples. Here are some starting points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-code

On the offchance you're using React, there's even a set of React controls for MSAL, making this even easier - see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react

Comment: Thank You for quick response. I have already referred to documentation that you have provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-code. In this microsoftTeams is used and this is deprecated.